# Adding hreflang tags automatically in WordPress multisite

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite, hreflang

I've managed to write a function that gets the job done, but I feel like there has to be a better way to do this.

I have a WordPress multisite network that is running with the subdirectory setup. There's a primary site that is in English and several sub-sites that have been mostly translated to other languages. Translation is ongoing and there is not an equivalent page/post for each site in the network yet. For a post that exists on the English site that is not yet on the Spanish site, an hreflang tag for `website.com/some-blog-post` will return a 404 for `website.com/es/some-blog-post`.

I've placed this function in the theme's `functions.php` file for the time being. The site theme is made with Timber/Twig and there is no `header.php` file, so to add this to a template or partial would require some structural refactoring. I'm using the 2-letter code as a text string for easy insertion to both the `hreflang` and corresponding subdirectory in the URL.

This seems like the most workable solution given the limitations, although PHP isn't my strong suit. If there is a better way I'm all for it.

```php
 /**
 * ADD HREFLANG ATTRIBUTES
 * Automatically append hreflang with network URL, language, and permalink to all pages
 */
function add_hreflang_attribute() {
    $site_url = "network_site_url()"; // base URL 
    $alt_langs = array( 'de', 'es', 'fr' ); // two-letter language code
    $page_path = substr(get_permalink(), strlen(home_url('/'))); // path of page after base URL

    // get primary English site URL and page path
    echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $site_url . $page_path . '" hreflang="en" />'. PHP_EOL;

    // loop through the alternative languages, and get the appropriate hreflang tag for each that exists
    foreach ($alt_langs as $lang) {
        $updated_url_lang_path = $site_url . $lang . '/' . $page_path;
        $url_headers = @get_headers($updated_url_lang_path);
        if($url_headers && strpos( $url_headers[0], '200')) {
            echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $updated_url_lang_path . '" hreflang="' . $lang . '" />'. PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

    // set primary as x-default
    echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $site_url . $page_path . '" hreflang="x-default" />';
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_hreflang_attribute', 1);
```

Again, it works, but I'd like to make this better if I can. Preemptive thanks for any pointers, and Happy New Year!

Comment: I ended up setting `$alt_langs = array( '', 'au', 'uk' );` to add the `uk` & `au` alternates on the main site, as without the `''`, the `'au` & `uk` alternates did not show on the main site.

Comment: I've [made adjustments](https://pastebin.com/ceYE7qt9), the main site `https://mandoestage.wpengine.com/features/` works fine, but the AU site doesn't work at all `https://mandoestage.wpengine.com/au/features/` (using the same theme). Any suggestions?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the greater context of your site, but my first guess would be not not have any empty items in your `$alt_langs` array. The home site is the default and the relevant `hreflang` for that isn't part of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: I have removed `''` from `$alt_langs`. The code works when I am logged in, but not in an incognito window where I am logged out. In the incognito window, I only see `<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/" hreflang="x-default" />`, not the `/au/, en-au` or `/uk/, en-gb`alternates.

Comment: See [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/405645/3206) for an alternative solution.