# Adding hreflang tags automatically in WordPress subdirectory multisite

Tags: php, wordpress

We have a WordPress MU subdirectory network setup:

- [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) - main website, USA, global
- [www.example.com/uk/](http://www.example.com/uk/) - to display for UK visitors
- [www.example.com/au/](http://www.example.com/au/) - to display for Australian visitors.

We want to add hreflang tags for each webpage, and exclude the `locations` custom post type.

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70581915/adding-hreflang-tags-automatically-in-wordpress-multisite), I've adjusted the code in the child theme's
`functions.php` to:

```
function add_hreflang_attribute() {
   $site_url = network_site_url(); // base URL
   $alt_langs = array( '', 'au', 'uk' ); // two-letter language code
   $page_path = substr(get_permalink(), strlen(home_url('/'))); // path of page after base URL
   
   if (!( is_singular( 'locations' ) ) ) {
           
       // loop through the alternative languages, and get the appropriate hreflang tag for each that exists
       foreach ($alt_langs as $lang) {
           $updated_url_lang_path = $site_url . $lang . '/' . $page_path;
           $url_headers = @get_headers($updated_url_lang_path);
           if($url_headers && strpos( $url_headers[0], '200')) {
               if ($lang == 'uk') {
                   echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $updated_url_lang_path . '" hreflang="en-gb" />'. PHP_EOL;
               } elseif ($lang == '') {
                 
               }
               else {
                   echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $updated_url_lang_path . '" hreflang="en-' . $lang . '" />'. PHP_EOL;
               }
           }
       }
       
       // set primary as x-default
       echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $site_url . $page_path . '" hreflang="x-default" />';
        
   }

}
```

This code works on the main website's home page & example page: `www.example.com/features/`;

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/au/features/" hreflang="en-au" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/uk/features/" hreflang="en-gb" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/features/" hreflang="x-default" />
```

and it works for the:

- AU site's home page,
- the AU site's features page: `https://www.example.com/au/features/`,

but on `www.example.com/uk/` it only produces:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/au/" hreflang="en-au" />
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
```

It is missing:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/uk/" hreflang="en-gb" />
```

The features page is a simple WordPress page.

Help appreciated.

**EDIT**

If I add `if ($lang == 'uk') {print_r(get_headers($updated_url_lang_path));}`, I see:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
    [1] => Server: nginx
    [2] => Date: Wed, 11 May 2022 22:08:04 GMT
    [3] => Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    [4] => Content-Length: 88422
    [5] => Connection: close
    [6] => Vary: Accept-Encoding
    [7] => Vary: Accept-Encoding
    [8] => Accept-CH: Sec-CH-UA-Mobile
    [9] => Link: <https://www.example.com/uk/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
    [10] => Link: <https://www.example.com/uk/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/10>; rel="alternate"; type="application/json"
    [11] => Link: <https://www.example.com/uk/>; rel=shortlink
    [12] => X-Powered-By: WP Engine
    [13] => X-Cacheable: SHORT
    [14] => Vary: Accept-Encoding,Cookie
    [15] => Cache-Control: max-age=600, must-revalidate
    [16] => X-Cache: HIT: 8
    [17] => X-Cache-Group: normal
    [18] => Accept-Ranges: bytes
    [19] => X-Orig-Cache-Control: no-cache
)
```

and the following is added properly:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/uk/" hreflang="en-gb" />
```

However, I only see this while logged into WordPress.

In an incognito window, at `https://www.example.com/uk/` I see (only):

```
<link rel="alternate" href="https://www.example.com/" hreflang="x-default" />
```

Comment: Reading your code, the missing <link> is not generated because `$url_headers = @get_headers($updated_url_lang_path);` is probably not returning a `HTTP 200` header, which you are looking for on this line: `if($url_headers && strpos( $url_headers[0], '200'))`. So what is the output of `get_headers("https://www.example.com/uk/")`?

Comment: @Piemol, thanks for your attention, see my edit to the question.

Comment: So what is the output of `print_r(get_headers("https://www.example.com/uk/"))` while incognito/not logged in? That is the most important part, then it's not working :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I altered the code to:

```
function mm_add_hreflang_attribute() {
    if (!( is_singular( 'locations' ) ) ) {
        $sites = array(
            array('', 'x-default'),
            array('en-gb/', 'en-gb'),
            array('en-au/', 'en-au'),
        );
        
        if ( is_post_type_archive('locations') ) {
            foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
                $site_url = network_site_url();
                $page_path = 'locations/';
                $geo_url = $site[0];
                $hreflang = $site[1];
                $url = $site_url . $geo_url . $page_path;
                echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $url . '" hreflang="' . $hreflang . '" />'. PHP_EOL;
            }
        } else {
            foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
                $site_url = network_site_url();
                $page_path = substr(get_permalink(), strlen(home_url('/')));
                $geo_url = $site[0];
                $hreflang = $site[1];
                $url = $site_url . $geo_url . $page_path;
                echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $url . '" hreflang="' . $hreflang . '" />'. PHP_EOL;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'mm_add_hreflang_attribute', 1);
```

which works well.

Comment: Better code than relying on `get_headers()` each page request :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hey Steve, Use this code, It will work well!!!**

```
function mm_add_hreflang_attribute() {
if (!( is_singular( 'locations' ) ) ) {
    $sites = array(
        array('', 'x-default'),
        array('en-gb/', 'en-gb'),
        array('en-au/', 'en-au'),
    );
    
    if ( is_post_type_archive('locations') ) {
        foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
            $site_url = network_site_url();
            $page_path = 'locations/';
            $geo_url = $site[0];
            $hreflang = $site[1];
            $url = $site_url . $geo_url . $page_path;
            echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $url . '" hreflang="' . $hreflang . '" />'. PHP_EOL;
        }
    } 
else 
{
 foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
    $site_url = network_site_url();
    $page_path = substr(get_permalink(), strlen(home_url('/')));
    $geo_url = $site[0];
    $hreflang = $site[1];
    $url = $site_url . $geo_url . $page_path;
    echo '<link rel="alternate" href="' . $url . '" hreflang="' . $hreflang . '" />'. PHP_EOL;
    }
   }
  }
}
add_action('wp_head', 'mm_add_hreflang_attribute', 1);
```

Comment: What is the difference between your code and the code in my answer, Juned?